# <<TclError: image "pyimage*" doesn't exist>> in python

Tags: tkinter

i`m a student to study python few days ago, and i interested in 'tkinter' nowadays.

i have no idea where is wrong in that code and error message below.

please help me..TT

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import tkinter as tk

banana=r'banana.gif'
bodercolor=[('aliceblue','#F0F8FF'),('blue','#000FF'),
             ('beige','#F5F5DC'),('cornsilk','#FFF8DC'),
              ('red','#ff0000'),('lightgreen','#90EE90')]

class BgChange:
    def __init__(self, label, color):   
        self.label = label
        self.color = color

    def __call__(self, event=None):
        self.label.configure(bg=self.color)

class MyWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master.title('select bordercolor')
        f_button=tk.Frame(self)
        f_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=5, pady=1)
        self.banana=tk.PhotoImage(file = banana)     
        label=tk.Label(self, image=self.banana,relief=tk.RAISED, bd=6)
        label.pack(side=tk.RIGHT,padx=7)

        for name, code in bodercolor:
            b=tk.Button(f_button, text=name,
                        bg=code, command=BgChange()) 
            b.pack(fill=tk.X)

if __name__== '__main__':
    MyWindow(tk.Tk()).mainloop()
```

**Error message**

```
runfile('C:/Users/User/Desktop/python_ex/report/문제2.py', wdir='C:/Users/User/Desktop/python_ex/report')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-14-8a31f2388234>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/User/Desktop/python_ex/report/문제2.py', wdir='C:/Users/User/Desktop/python_ex/report')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/python_ex/report/문제2.py", line 35, in <module>
    win = MyWindow(root)

  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/python_ex/report/문제2.py", line 24, in __init__
    label=tk.Label(self, image=self.banana,relief=tk.RAISED, bd=6)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2766, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2299, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))

TclError: image "pyimage10" doesn't exist
```

Comment: ```

  File "<ipython-input-2-5dcb34d10bfd>", line 35, in <module>
    MyWindow(tk.Tk()).mainloop()

  File "<ipython-input-2-5dcb34d10bfd>", line 24, in __init__
    label=tk.Label(self, image=self.banana,relief=tk.RAISED, bd=6)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2766, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2299, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))

TclError: image "pyimage2" doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.
You should provide a **Minimal Reproducible Example**

According to your error:

> TclError: image "pyimage10" doesn't exist

I provide the full\absolute path which is in my case

```
self.banana='C:\\Users\\Python\\banana.gif'
```

I also keep a reference to the image:

```
self.master.banana= PhotoImage(file = self.banana)
```

Here the complete code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Frame, PhotoImage

class MyWindow():
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.banana='C:\\Users\\Python\\banana.gif'
        self.master = master
        self.master.title('select bordercolor')

        self.f_button = Frame(self.master)
        self.f_button.pack(side= "left", padx=5, pady=1)
        self.master.banana= PhotoImage(file = self.banana) 

        self.label= Label(self.master, image=self.master.banana, relief="raised", bd=6)
        self.label.pack(side="right", padx=7)

if __name__== '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    MyWindow(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

You have other errors in your code but this is an other question worth. See tkinter command option in buttons!

Comment: reaaaally appreciate your advice!
i`ll try it, thank you!

Comment: please set this question as answered if that solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I was working with tkinter and found the same error but interestingly i notice a pattern like some time it work and sometime it show this error!

the easy fix for this is run this code first :

import tkinter as tk

root = tk.TK()

root.mainloop()

after that is will show more than one Tkinter windows just close all and then run your code
**FROM START I.E FROM IMPORTING THE LIBRAIRES AGAIN AND THEN RUNNING THE CODE.**

I hope this will fix the issue.